# What files does the mac terminal load first?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

A while ago I installed a program called "j" for the terminal. It was supposed to make things simpler. However, after a while of using it I decided I didn't really need it and trashed it. Now ever time I open the terminal it says:

> -bash: /Users/aslet/j.sh: No such file or directory

I have no idea what file is telling the terminal to look for the program, so some help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can also look for the line doing `grep "j.sh" *` in your home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fire up the terminal, content from the following gets loaded upon existence:

```
 /etc/profile
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login   (if .bash_profile does not exist)
~/.profile      (if .bash_login does not exist)
```

It appears that the one of the file listed above still has reference to the `j.sh` script which no longer exists after you removed the program.

Comment the line which calls that script and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: I don't have a .bash_login file in my home directory in Mac OSX 10.6.8.

Comment: Right. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Jaypal That's the thing. I already checked all these files and it's not there.

Comment: @Aslet Check your `/etc/profile`. If you don't have any reference in all of the above files then the reference has to be in `/etc/profile`.

Comment: @Aslet Great! I have added that to the answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Check .bashrc and .bash_profile in your home directory.  The leading . means they are hidden files.  Look for a line containing the directory listed in the error message.